# How open directory in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

in my app i have list of files that shows in ListActivity now i want add extra option like windows :(Open folder location) to open directory off this file i test some code but not work throw exception:

```
File file=new File(path);
        Uri url = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(url);
        startActivity(intent);
```

exeption :

```
03-08 21:14:55.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15708): 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/extSdCard/Bluetooth }
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openFolder()
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
+ "/Bluetooth /");
   intent.setDataAndType(uri);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
  }
```

Comment: This will not work with all android file manager apps though!

Comment: setDataAndType need type ?

Comment: @kyle The chosen app can open the file from the app itself ? No means what should do to open the file from the chosen app itself?